# Eclipse RCP class visibility in different bundles

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, bundle, rcp

Lets assume that we have two Eclipse RCP Projects A and B.
A is the bundle that contains JAR files. MANIFEST.MF in B contains:
"`Require-Bundle: A`" which includes A with all the JARs inside B.

I want to use in A: `Class.forName("somepackage.BClass")` where `BClass` is the class that exists in B.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Your B bundle MANIFEST.MF must include an `Export-Package:` statement which lists each package that the bundle is making available to other bundles.

```
Export-Package: somepackage,
 anotherpackage,
 yetanotherpackage
```

In the MANIFEST.MF editor you can do this on the 'Runtime' tab in the 'Exported Packages' section.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to import the *.jar placed in your plugin A in the *build.properties* file, like:

```
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               lib/Some.jar
```

After that you have to export the packages by using the MANIFEST Editor of Eclipse. Open the MANIFEST.MF with the corresponding editor an select tab *Runtime*.

Use button *Add* to add all packages you want to export to other plugin, which depend on A.

[Exported Packages](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Fmanifest_editor%2Fruntime.htm)